# how to get execution time, total count, ip address who hit it in nodejs api

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, rest

Basically what I want to do is to get a particular endpoint last execution time, total number of times api executed today and ip address of each machine who hits the api and the application response time of each time api hits. How to achieve this in nodeJS? Basically it is rest api auditing system.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing related specifically to Node here per se, you can log every request and the needed details somewhere (i.e. a plain database). It might be handy to create a middleware that wraps all API endpoints `(client -> middleware -> api endpoint function)` that contains the logic for this.

Since you're using NodeJS, you can create a callback mechanism for measuring response times, i.e. your middleware can provide a callback function to your API endpoint controller(s) that the controller invokes when it sends the response to the user (after `res.send()` if you're using Express).

Comment: Can you write code for that.The main problem is facing how to get response time of a particular endpoint.It would be helpful if you could give javascript code for this question.I am new to development world Help from you will be of great use.

Comment: I can't provide code as you didn't and it'd be too lengthy. I've lined out the abstract as to how to do it, you log the time that the request arrives, and in your callback function you log the time that the response is sent. The difference between the two times is the response time.

Answer (score 0):

I can answer some of your queries :-

IP -> IP address of the machine that hits the api is present in the request object req.connection.remoteAddress in expressjs(It may not be proper if your request is being routed over a proxy like Akamai, in that case turn on True-Client-IP header in akamai)

Count -> make a db write every time a particular endpoint is requested. Just put it right before your entry point function(api) sends response.

Response time of api - just put this at the start and end of your entry point function.
At the start :-
let start = process.hrtime();

Before api sends response :-
endTime = process.hrtime(start);
endTime = Math.round(((endTime[0] * 1000) + (endTime[1] / 1000000)));

Maybe you can wrap this in a function. It will give you the time elapsed in milliseconds and you can store that too somewhere for each iteration.